# mixed dataframe of list of character vectors into uniform dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr, mixed

I am trying to break up strings as columns using the stringr package.

```
> df <- dput(head(facs,3))
structure(list(geo_accession = structure(1:3, .Names = c("V2", 
"V3", "V4"), .Label = c("GSM1494875", "GSM1494877", "GSM1494879", 
"GSM1494881", "GSM1494883", "GSM1494885", "GSM1494887", "GSM1494889", 
"GSM1494891", "GSM1494893", "GSM1494895", "GSM1494897", "GSM1494899", 
"GSM1494901", "GSM1494903", "GSM1494906", "GSM1494908", "GSM1494910", 
"GSM1494912", "GSM1494914", "GSM1494917", "GSM1494919", "GSM1494921", 
"GSM1494923"), class = "factor"), title = structure(1:3, .Names = c("V2", 
"V3", "V4"), .Label = c("2818 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 1 - mAdbID:125971", 
"2818 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 2 - mAdbID:125972", "2818 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 3 - mAdbID:125973", 
"2818 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 4 - mAdbID:125974", "2818 - Untreated TIL - repeat 1 - mAdbID:125975", 
"2818 - Untreated TIL - repeat 2 - mAdbID:125976", "2818 - Untreated TIL - repeat 3 - mAdbID:125977", 
"2818 - Untreated TIL - repeat 4 - mAdbID:125978", "3289 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 1 - mAdbID:125979", 
"3289 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 2 - mAdbID:125980", "3289 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 3 - mAdbID:125981", 
"3289 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 4 - mAdbID:125982", "3289 - Untreated TIL - repeat 1 - mAdbID:125983", 
"3289 - Untreated TIL - repeat 2 - mAdbID:125984", "3289 - Untreated TIL - repeat 3 - mAdbID:125985", 
"3289 - Untreated TIL - repeat 4 - mAdbID:125986", "3784 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 1 - mAdbID:125987", 
"3784 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 2 - mAdbID:125988", "3784 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 3 - mAdbID:125989", 
"3784 - Akt treated TIL - repeat 4 - mAdbID:125990", "3784 - Untreated TIL - repeat 1 - mAdbID:125991", 
"3784 - Untreated TIL - repeat 2 - mAdbID:125992", "3784 - Untreated TIL - repeat 3 - mAdbID:125993", 
"3784 - Untreated TIL - repeat 4 - mAdbID:125994"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("geo_accession", 
"title"), row.names = c("GSM1494875", "GSM1494877", "GSM1494879"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Right now it's a 2 column dataframe.

```
> sapply(df, class)
geo_accession         title 
 "factor"      "factor"
```

If I use `str_split_fixed`,

```
> df$title = str_split_fixed(df[,"title"], " - ", 4)
> df
           geo_accession title.1         title.2  title.3       title.4
GSM1494875    GSM1494875    2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 1 mAdbID:125971
GSM1494877    GSM1494877    2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 2 mAdbID:125972

> sapply(df, class)
geo_accession         title 
 "factor"      "matrix"
```

What I'd like to see is a 5 column dataframe, instead of a 2 column mixed dataframe (factor, matrix).

```
> df
       geo_accession title1          title2   title3        title4
GSM1494875    GSM1494875   2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 1 mAdbID:125971
GSM1494877    GSM1494877   2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 2 mAdbID:125972

> sapply(df, class)
geo_accession       title.1       title.2       title.3       title.4 
 "factor"      "factor"      "factor"      "factor"      "factor"
```

I don't know how to clean up a mixed dataframe. How can I convert this into a 5-column dataframe?

Comment: See `?tidyr::separate`

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Please use `dput` to share your data in a reproducible way as per the R tag description

Comment: Thanks to the other SO users for the answers! Is this now an acceptable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(title, paste0('title',1:4) ,' - ')

           geo_accession title1          title2   title3        title4
1 GSM1494875  GSM1494875   2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 1 mAdbID:125971
2  GSM1494877 GSM1494877   2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 2 mAdbID:125972
```

Comment: That worked great! Being able to string operations together makes the code much more readable to me :)

Answer (score 1):

The output of `str_split_fixed` is a `list` of `vectors`.  Assigning a `list` to a single column is the cause of the problem.  One way is to assign it to multiple columns or otherwise, we can fix it with `do.call(data.frame`, i.e.

```
facs1 <- do.call(data.frame, facs)
```

---

Or we can use `base R` methods with `read.csv/read.table` after removing the spaces before and after the `-` and then `cbind` with the first column

```
facs2 <- cbind(facs[1], read.csv(text=gsub("\\s+-\\s+", "-", facs$title), 
          sep="-", header=FALSE, col.names = paste0("title.", 1:4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
facs2
#           geo_accession title.1         title.2  title.3       title.4
#GSM1494875    GSM1494875    2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 1 mAdbID:125971
#GSM1494877    GSM1494877    2818 Akt treated TIL repeat 2 mAdbID:125972

str(facs2)
#'data.frame':   2 obs. of  5 variables:
#$ geo_accession: chr  "GSM1494875" "GSM1494877"
#$ title.1      : int  2818 2818
#$ title.2      : chr  "Akt treated TIL" "Akt treated TIL"
#$ title.3      : chr  "repeat 1" "repeat 2"
#$ title.4      : chr  "mAdbID:125971" "mAdbID:125972"
```

---

Or a compact option is `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(facs, "title", " - ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and the additional methods!